# How to get the Model from an ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test and I call an action method like this

```
var result = controller.Action(123);
```

result is `ActionResult` and I need to get the model somehow, anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In my version of ASP.NET MVC there is no `Action` method on Controller. However, if you meant the `View` method, here's how you can unit test that the result contains the correct model.

First of all, if you only return ViewResult from a particular Action, declare the method as [returning ViewResult instead of ActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021568/must-asp-net-mvc-controller-methods-return-actionresult).

As an example, consider this Index action

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return this.View(this.userViewModelService.GetUsers());
}
```

you can get to the model as easily as this

```
var result = sut.Index().ViewData.Model;
```

If your method signature's return type is ActionResult instead of ViewResult, you will need to cast it to ViewResult first.

Comment: It's better to cast to ViewResultBase (this covers partials); also (rarely) one may consider using reflection to check ViewData/Model properties and get Model (in case there're unknown view result types).

Comment: Good point on ViewResultBase, but why would you ever use Reflection for something like this?

Answer (score 20):

We placed the following piece in a testsbase.cs allowing for typed models in the tests a la

```
ActionResult actionResult = ContextGet<ActionResult>();
var model = ModelFromActionResult<SomeViewModelClass>(actionResult);
```

ModelFromActionResult...

```
public T ModelFromActionResult<T>(ActionResult actionResult)
{
    object model;
    if (actionResult.GetType() == typeof(ViewResult))
    {
        ViewResult viewResult = (ViewResult)actionResult;
        model = viewResult.Model;
    }
    else if (actionResult.GetType() == typeof(PartialViewResult))
    {
        PartialViewResult partialViewResult = (PartialViewResult)actionResult;
        model = partialViewResult.Model;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Actionresult of type {0} is not supported by ModelFromResult extractor.", actionResult.GetType()));
    }
    T typedModel = (T)model;
    return typedModel;
}
```

An example using a Index page and List:

```
var actionResult = controller.Index();
var model = ModelFromActionResult<List<TheModel>>((ActionResult)actionResult.Result);
```

Comment: Great I combined it with http://mkramar.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/onactionexecuting-and-onactionexecuted.html (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591720/how-do-i-unit-test-my-asp-net-mvc-controllers-onactionexecuting-method)
So it looks like:             ActionResult actionResult = Invoke(() =>  new SomeController().Index());
            var RestultViewModel = ModelFromActionResult<List<SomeRecords>>(actionResult); Very happy with this test now.

Comment: If you would like to find more improvements based on the same techniques please refer to my newly github project which combines yet more features in an easy to use way.
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/850277/ASP-NET-MVC-End-to-End-Integration-Testing

Answer (score 12):

consider a = ActionResult;

```
ViewResult p = (ViewResult)a;
p.ViewData.Model
```

Comment: This is an invalid cast.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat cheating but a very trivial way to do so in .NET4

```
dynamic result = controller.Action(123);

result.Model
```

Used this today in a unit test. Might be worth some sanity checks such as:

```
Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result); 
Assert.IsType<MyModel>(result.Model);

Assert.Equal(123, result.Model.Id);
```

You could skip the first one if the result is going to be a view or partial result depending on the input.