# unit test actions decorated with Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, inversion-of-control

I have simple asp.net mvc application which uses custom `membership` and `role provider`. After setting all in place I use `[Authorize]`inside controller actions to allow/deny access to certain user groups. Now I want to move further and try to unit test every controller which uses `[Authorize]` attribute.

I was thinking to use Unity Ioc and Moq.
Any good suggestion from where to start, basic steps with some code examples or tutorials to share?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877225/how-do-i-unit-test-a-controller-method-that-has-the-authorize-attribute-applie

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the below approach. Basically you can write a Unit test to ensure your action is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute.

See my blog post for more information. This approach should work nicely with your Unit Test.

http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/2012/12/04/Simple-test-helper-MVC-Action-has-decorated-with-a-certain-attribute.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I answered this in another thread - the blog post link above is "ok", but I wanted to test the actual attribute on the actual controller I was testing:

[Answer: How to test custom MVC attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20846153/1388341)